# .onclick button not executing function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have a problem with my .onclick function not executing the function specified in my script file. Here's my code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var quotes = [
    ["“If you are distressed by anything external, the pain is not due to the thing itself, but to your estimate of it; and this you have the power to revoke at any moment.”", "Marcus Aurelius"],["“The average man is a conformist, accepting miseries and disasters with the stoicism of a cow standing in the rain.”", "Colin Wilson"],
    ["“Never let the future disturb you. You will meet it, if you have to, with the same weapons of reason which today arm you against the present.”", "Marcus Aurelius"],
    ["“Warriors should suffer their pain silently.”","Erin Hunter"],
    ["“Complaining does not work as a strategy. We all have finite time and energy. Any time we spend whining is unlikely to help us achieve our goals. And it won't make us happier.”", "Randy Pausch"],
    ["“It is the power of the mind to be unconquerable.”", "Seneca"],
    ["“How do you defeat terrorism? Don’t be terrorized.”", "Salman Rushdie"],
    ["“It is not the man who has too little that is poor, but the one who hankers after more.”", "Seneca"],
    ["“What really frightens and dismays us is not external events themselves, but the way in which we think about them. It is not things that disturb us, but our interpretation of their significance.”", "Epictetus"],
    ["“For death remembered should be like a mirror, who tells us life’s but breath, to trust it error.”", "Shakespeare"],
    ["“No one saves us but ourselves. No one can and no one may. We ourselves must walk the path.”", "Buddha"],
    ["“You only lose what you cling to.”", "Buddha"],
    ["“Man suffers only because he takes seriously what the gods made for fun.”", "Alan W. Watts"],
    ["“If there is any religion that could respond to the needs of modern science, it would be Buddhism.”", "Albert Einstein"],
    ["“We are not going in circles, we are going upwards. The path is a spiral; we have already climbed many steps.”", "Hermann Hesse"],
    ["“Treat every moment as your last. It is not preparation for something else.”", "Shunryu Suzuki"],
    ["“Better than a thousand hollow words is one word that brings peace.”", "Buddha"],
    ["“Life is painful. It has thorns, like the stem of a rose. Culture and art are the roses that bloom on the stem. The flower is yourself, your humanity. Art is the liberation of the humanity inside yourself.”", "Daisaku Ikeda"],
    ["“Learning to let go should be learned before learning to get. Life should be touched, not strangled. You’ve got to relax, let it happen at times, and at others move forward with it.”", "Ray Bradbury"]  
];


var randomInt =  Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length) + 1);

// Generate random number
// Get number's position from array 
var aQuote = function() {
    return quotes[randomInt][0] + "";
};

var aQuoteAuthor = function() {
    return quotes[randomInt][1] + "";
};


// Change textblock into quote + author
// Display quote on page
// Display author on page

function changeButton() {
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = aQuote();
    document.getElementById('quoteAuthor').innerHTML = aQuoteAuthor();
};

// Register button press 
document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton();
```

And this is my html:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="u-full-width">
        <div class="quotediv">
            <h5 id="quote" class="text-primary-color">“Imagine smiling after a slap in the face. Then think of doing it twenty-four hours a day.”</h5>
            <p id="quoteAuthor" class="light-primary-color">Markus Zusak<p>
            <button id="aButton" type="button button-primary" class="primary-text-color"> NEW QUOTE</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src ="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

The first weird thing is that the function changeButton() gets invoked automatically on page load without a function call. So on every page load there's a new quote generated and displayed. The second weird thing is that the button itself does not generate and change the quote via the function changeButton().

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

P.S. I'm a coding newbie. This is my first question on SO. I tried to follow the guidelines for specificity but if you have any tips or comments on my question formulation, please let me know! :)

Comment: who is calling `changeButton` function

Comment: How about attaching an event listener to the element `document.getElementById('aButton').addEventListener('click', changeButton());`

Comment: try this `document.getElementById('#id').on('click',changebutton());`

Comment: Looks like document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton(); is causing problem. If you just want to register the event handler just say     document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are executing the function and assigning the return value to onclick.

```
document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton();
```

You should be assigning the function itself to onclick like so (Note it doesnt have "()" at the end)

```
document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton;
```

Even better would be to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) like so

```
document.getElementById('aButton').addEventListener('click', changeButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like that:

**document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton**

what you were doing is binding event and simultaneously executing it.

```js
document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton

function changeButton() {
console.log("yes");
}
```

```html
<button id="aButton">
Button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `onClick` listener using

```
document.getElementById('aButton').addEventListener("click", changeButton);
```

Using:

```
document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton();
```

You just assign the return value of the function rather than assign the function to the click event! This line:

```
document.getElementById('aButton').onclick = changeButton;
```

Actually assigns the function to the click event (note, no brackets so it isn't executed, it's assigned as a variable).

```js
function changeButton() {
 alert("Hello")
}

document.getElementById('aButton').addEventListener("click", changeButton);
```

```html
<button id="aButton">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

move your script to head section it will work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var quotes = [
    ["“If you are distressed by anything external, the pain is not due to the thing itself, but to your estimate of it; and this you have the power to revoke at any moment.”", "Marcus Aurelius"],["“The average man is a conformist, accepting miseries and disasters with the stoicism of a cow standing in the rain.”", "Colin Wilson"],
    ["“Never let the future disturb you. You will meet it, if you have to, with the same weapons of reason which today arm you against the present.”", "Marcus Aurelius"],
    ["“Warriors should suffer their pain silently.”","Erin Hunter"],
    ["“Complaining does not work as a strategy. We all have finite time and energy. Any time we spend whining is unlikely to help us achieve our goals. And it won't make us happier.”", "Randy Pausch"],
    ["“It is the power of the mind to be unconquerable.”", "Seneca"],
    ["“How do you defeat terrorism? Don’t be terrorized.”", "Salman Rushdie"],
    ["“It is not the man who has too little that is poor, but the one who hankers after more.”", "Seneca"],
    ["“What really frightens and dismays us is not external events themselves, but the way in which we think about them. It is not things that disturb us, but our interpretation of their significance.”", "Epictetus"],
    ["“For death remembered should be like a mirror, who tells us life’s but breath, to trust it error.”", "Shakespeare"],
    ["“No one saves us but ourselves. No one can and no one may. We ourselves must walk the path.”", "Buddha"],
    ["“You only lose what you cling to.”", "Buddha"],
    ["“Man suffers only because he takes seriously what the gods made for fun.”", "Alan W. Watts"],
    ["“If there is any religion that could respond to the needs of modern science, it would be Buddhism.”", "Albert Einstein"],
    ["“We are not going in circles, we are going upwards. The path is a spiral; we have already climbed many steps.”", "Hermann Hesse"],
    ["“Treat every moment as your last. It is not preparation for something else.”", "Shunryu Suzuki"],
    ["“Better than a thousand hollow words is one word that brings peace.”", "Buddha"],
    ["“Life is painful. It has thorns, like the stem of a rose. Culture and art are the roses that bloom on the stem. The flower is yourself, your humanity. Art is the liberation of the humanity inside yourself.”", "Daisaku Ikeda"],
    ["“Learning to let go should be learned before learning to get. Life should be touched, not strangled. You’ve got to relax, let it happen at times, and at others move forward with it.”", "Ray Bradbury"]  
];


var randomInt =  Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length) + 1);

// Generate random number
// Get number's position from array 
var aQuote = function() {
    return quotes[randomInt][0] + "";
};

var aQuoteAuthor = function() {
    return quotes[randomInt][1] + "";
};


// Change textblock into quote + author
// Display quote on page
// Display author on page

function changeButton() {
    alert();
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = aQuote();
    document.getElementById('quoteAuthor').innerHTML = aQuoteAuthor();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="u-full-width">
        <div class="quotediv">
            <h5 id="quote" class="text-primary-color">“Imagine smiling after a slap in the face. Then think of doing it twenty-four hours a day.”</h5>
            <p id="quoteAuthor" class="light-primary-color">Markus Zusak<p>
            <button id="aButton" type="button button-primary"  class="primary-text-color"> NEW QUOTE</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```